# Ionic Capacitor Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat found in modules jetified-android-support-v4

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I already added the jetifier to gradle.properties and furthermore there aren't any answers to my questions on the internet that i could find. I am using 1 old package named phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner which is why i still need jetifier to convert it to androidx

gradle.properties:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true

# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Error from Android studio:

`Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat found in modules jetified-android-support-v4 (android-support-v4.jar) and media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0)`

and this goes on for a lot more lines than these.

and this is my package.json from my ionic project:

```
{
  "name": "Redacted",
  "version": "1.5.0",
  "author": "Redacted",
  "homepage": "Redacted",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "jetifier"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^17.1.1",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/barcode-scanner": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/file": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/file-opener": "^6.6.0",
    "@capacitor-community/barcode-scanner": "^4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "5.6.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "5.6.0",
    "@capacitor/device": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/ios": "5.6.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "5.0.8",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "5.0.7",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.14.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.15.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^7.6.6",
    "@ionic/core": "^7.6.6",
    "@ionic/storage-angular": "^4.0.0",
    "android.support.v4": "21.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "intl-tel-input-mobile": "^1.0.6",
    "macos-release": "^3.0.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.2",
    "ngx-mask": "^17.0.4",
    "ngx-pipes": "^3.2.2",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.68",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.0",
    "swiper": "^11.0.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1701.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "17.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "17.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "17.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "17.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "17.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^17.1.1",
    "@capacitor/cli": "5.6.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^11.0.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.11.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "6.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "6.19.0",
    "cordova-open-native-settings": "^1.5.2",
    "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~9.0.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "browserslist": [
    "Chrome >=61",
    "ChromeAndroid >=61",
    "Firefox >=63",
    "Firefox ESR",
    "Edge >=79",
    "Safari >=13",
    "iOS >=13"
  ]
}
```

What is the problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I am using 1 old package named phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner which is why i still need jetifier to convert it to androidx

Remove this old plugin, the jetify dependency is cause of issue. No need for androidX anymore.

There is a better alternative that will fix your problem: [@capacitor-mlkit/barcode-scanning](https://capawesome.io/plugins/mlkit/barcode-scanning/)

Also you should look into changing all cordova plugins to available capacitor alternatives instead. you're app will be a lot lighter and work smoother.